# Appium: Assert splash screen

Tags: java, ios, appium, splash-screen

I want to verify logo appeared on the splash screen. But I can't find its locator because when I open Appium Inspector the logo disappears very fast.

How can I verify it?

**I am using:**
Appium Version: 1.15.1
Mac OS Catalina
Java 1.8

Steps to reproduce:

1. Start Appium inspector
2. Launch capabilities
3. Observe the Splash screen, it will stay for a very short time (no time to find the element for logo)
4. Landing Screen appears

[image]

Comment: Can you please provide some way to reproduce your problem?

Comment: Added steps. But it's not a bug, it's more of a question "How you did it?" "How do you verify logo on splash screen?"

Answer (score 0):

You can get the page_source immediately after opening the app and store it on a variable:

```
page_source = driver.page_source
```

the you can assert the element is in the page_source or not.

```
page_source = driver.page_source
locator: '//android.widget.TextView[2]/android.widget.TextView[1]'
assert locator in page_source
```

This works only with absolute xpath.

(Syntax is in Python)